# RegEx in Oracle SQL seems not to work

Tags: sql, regex, oracle

I've got a small issue with regex in oracle.
I have a table as follows with 3 cases of string formats:

In my table, col1 holds the Strings I have, col2 is target.

Case 1: W1234W4321
Case 2: W1234,W4321
Case 3: W1234/W4321
(Length and and actual numbers vary)

Now I've set up this little regex: `[\d,/]W.*` to separate the two values after decimal, comma and slash.
I've tested the result in the tool RegExBuddy where he result is as expected.
When updating my table with following query, cases 2 and 3 are being updated, case 1 is still null in col 2.

```
update nyTable set col2 = regexp_substr(col1, '[\d,/]W.*');
```

Is this some issue related to oracle (maybe not understanding the `\d`)?

Comment: what is your expected result?`

Comment: As stated above the second value separated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14251/adfns_regexp.htm

\d: A digit character. It is equivalent to the POSIX class [[:digit:]].

Comment: Phew, didn't find that one. So I was at least on the right way :D